# new MyObject() is not equal to new funcion MyObejct how to get them equal?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, javascript-objects

I have a function that uses case to return an object

```
    function GetModel(mymodel){

    var mydatamodel = null; 
    switch(mymodel)
    {
    case 'Contact':
    mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                    id: "__KEY",
                                    fields: {
                                    __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                    __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                    firstName: { type: "string" },
                                    middleName: { type: "string" },                                                         
                                    lastName: { type: "string" }
                                    }                               
                                });
                                break;

    case 'Address':
    mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                    id: "__KEY",
                                    fields: {
                                    __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                    __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                    street: { type: "string" }
                                    }                               
                                });
                                break;
    case 'ContactType':     
    mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                    id: "__KEY",
                                    fields: {
                                    __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                    __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                    name: { type: "string" }                                
                                    }                               
                                });
                                break;
    };

    return mydatamodel  
    };

//Try to create new instance
var mymodel = new GetModel("Contact")
```

Now this function does return an object but the object is not the same as
using the below code to create a new object which is what I need

```
 var mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                    id: "__KEY",
                                    fields: {
                                    __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                    __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                    firstName: { type: "string" },
                                    middleName: { type: "string" },                                                         
                                    lastName: { type: "string" }
                                    }                               
                                });

//Create new object;
var mymodel = new mydatamodel();
```

This works as expected and creates a new instance of the kendoui.datamodel where
the function returns the kendoui.data.modal.... as a function and not a new instance of the object

I would like to be able to call a switch function because I want this code in a different .js file then the main .html page for code seperation.  So how would
I go about getting the above function GetModel to act in the same way as the
var = kendoui.data.model... is working

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Just a side note, `Objects` are compared by reference, so two different instances of the same object/constructor are not equal, [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/kJcZK/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the new operator on your function.

Just make the function return an instance like this:

```
function GetModel(mymodel){

var mydatamodel = null; 
switch(mymodel)
{
case 'Contact':
mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                id: "__KEY",
                                fields: {
                                __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                firstName: { type: "string" },
                                middleName: { type: "string" },                                                         
                                lastName: { type: "string" }
                                }                               
                            });
                            break;

case 'Address':
mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                id: "__KEY",
                                fields: {
                                __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                street: { type: "string" }
                                }                               
                            });
                            break;
case 'ContactType':     
mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
                                id: "__KEY",
                                fields: {
                                __KEY: { type: "string" },
                                __STAMP: { type: "number" },
                                ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },                                                                
                                name: { type: "string" }                                
                                }                               
                            });
                            break;
};

return new mydatamodel();
};
```

And use your creator function like this:

```
var mymodel = GetModel("Contact");
```

EDIT

Or use you code like this:

```
var mymodel = new (GetModel("Contact"))();
```

Comment: I understand that but  using new returns a differenct object which I need then just var mymodel = GetModel('Contact') but var model - new GetModel('Contact') returns the same as var mymodel = GetModeld('Contact') but not the same as var mymodel = new mydatamodel()

Comment: Edited answer to be sure you get what I mean. Hav you tried that?

Comment: No :( but thanks,  I already am using var mymodel = GetModel("Contact"); but I need that function to return a new instance and not just the object.

Comment: Check my answer. The function should return an instance.

Comment: You can also try calling you original function like this:
var mymodel = new (GetModel("Contact"))();

Comment: I see, but I tried that already and it still is not the same as new mydatamodel, I thought that would work as well but looking at the debugger the objects are similar but also very different, the new mydatamodel has many other proprties and functions defined when it gets created, I think the kendoui.data.model does something different when a new instance of itself is created

Comment: I say if you need to achieve the same thing the second block of code in your question does, but through a function, this is where to look. It should be exactly the same... Best thing would be to publish something we could work on (jsFiddle?)

Comment: Great that works var mymodel = new (GetModel("Contact"))();  I had previously tried the below which returned an object but not new, still very unfamiliar with javascript syntax and its meanings, arggghh I have been working at this one for awhile.  THANK YOU very very much!!!! 
var mymodel = new GetModel("Contact");

Comment: Again thanks your a life savor, damn got a headache from this one!!